# SFTP from a location other than /home/username in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

I am using Apache Camel's SFTP component to pick up files using SFTP from a Linux server. The problem is when I login using SFTP to the server, it is logging in to the directory */home/username* in the server. I am able to SFTP from directories which are subdirectories of /home/username but cannot change the directory to any directory other than /home/username. Like my file resides in a directory in /opt/u001 and cannot SFTP files from there. Please help.

Comment: Absolute path is not supported in sftp component. You need to change path to be relative to home directory. eg `../../opt/u001/`

Comment: I am forming the sftp component like this: sftp://<host>:<port>/<directory>?username=<username&password=<password>. I tried to form the sftp component like this: sftp://<host>:<port>/../../opt/u001?username=<username>&password=<password>, but it threw exception that the endpoint cannot be resolved.

Comment: This worked, thanks.

Comment: Hello @Anirban
Could you please show your working URL?

Comment: @Andrej - As suggested above, my working URL is like the one suggested above i.e.. sftp://localhost:8080/../../myDirectory. I will not be able to show the exact URL since I do not have the code with me now and cannot run it either